# Append value of type List to a map

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class of type Produit

```
class Produit {
 String? nom;
 double? prix;
 int? quantite;
 Produit({this.nom, this.prix, this.quantite});
}
```

I have a List of type Produit

```
List<Produit> listeProduits = [
.
. 
.
 ]
```

and i have this map

```
Map<int, List<Produit>> listePanier = {};
```

I'm trying to append a new value of type `Produit` to this map each time a button is pressed .

Comment: Well, what does the `key` represent? Your maps uses a `int` as the key which is needed to access or assign a list in the map.

Comment: But I can recommend looking at the `update` method if you want to have different logic depending on if the `key` are already in the map or not: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-core/Map/update.html

Comment: my concern here is the value of the map is of type List<Produit> and i'm trying each time a button is pressed to add an element to the value list of type Produit

Comment: Well, it does not sound like you are going to append anything to the map but rather the list inside the map for a given key? I am not sure I understand your problem and what you are trying to do.

Comment: exactly, i'm trying to append an item to the list inside the map

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using the [`update`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-core/Map/update.html) method on [`Map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-core/Map-class.html) to make so we handle situations where the `key` are already in the list (where we then want to append to the existing list) and where the key is missing (where we then want to create a new list with out element):

```dart
void main() {
  final Map<int, List<String>> myMap = {
    1: ['String1', 'String2']
  };

  print(myMap);
  // {1: [String1, String2]}

  String newValueToList = 'NewString3';

  // Example of what happens in case the key already exist
  myMap.update(1, (list) => list..add(newValueToList),
      ifAbsent: () => [newValueToList]);

  print(myMap);
  // {1: [String1, String2, NewString3]}

  newValueToList = 'NewString4';

  // Example of what happens if the key does not already exist. In this case
  // we create a new list with the new item
  myMap.update(2, (list) => list..add(newValueToList),
      ifAbsent: () => [newValueToList]);

  print(myMap);
  // {1: [String1, String2, NewString3], 2: [NewString4]}
}
```

We can also create an extension to help us doing this:

```dart
void main() {
  final Map<int, List<String>> myMap = {
    1: ['String1', 'String2']
  };

  print(myMap);
  // {1: [String1, String2]}

  myMap.appendToList(1, 'NewString3');

  print(myMap);
  // {1: [String1, String2, NewString3]}

  myMap.appendToList(2, 'NewString4');

  print(myMap);
  // {1: [String1, String2, NewString3], 2: [NewString4]}
}

extension AppendToListOnMapWithListsExtension<K, V> on Map<K, List<V>> {
  void appendToList(K key, V value) =>
      update(key, (list) => list..add(value), ifAbsent: () => [value]);
}
```